# Russian version of "When All You Have Is A Hammer, Everything Looks Like A Nail"

Tags: идиомы

What would be the Russian equivalent of "When All You Have Is A Hammer, Everything Looks Like A Nail", or an idiom of a similar sentiment?

Edit: This idiom means that if you only have one tool, you will use it for everything, even if it is not the right tool for the job.

Comment: Hi and welcome to Russian.SE! Could you please add an explanation of this idiom to the post? Thank you!

Comment: Кто о чём, а вшивый о бане (people talk about different things, a person who is plagued by lice always talks about a bath)

Comment: Чтобы он ни собирал, получался автомат Калашникова (he tried to assemble different designs, but the result was always a Kalashnikov assault rifle)

Answer (score 3):

I think you can use a literal translation, e.g. (from https://ru.citaty.net/tsitaty/655283-abrakham-maslou-avraam-maslov-ia-predpolagaiu-chto-esli-edinstvennyi-instrument-k/):

- Когда у тебя в руках молоток, все задачи кажутся гвоздями.
- Для человека с молотком все выглядит как гвоздь.
- etc.

The meaning is pretty understandable, and such phrases are actually used (in different forms), e.g. [example 1](https://zen.yandex.ru/media/id/5b7c0c62104fe600a812963e/esli-ty-molotok-to-vse-vokrug-gvozdi-5de49c263642b600afe51d60), [example 2](https://www.ckofr.com/psixologiya/873-professionalnaya-deformacziya) (these are the result of some random googling). I actually remember seeing this phrase "in the wild" in some Russian texts before.

Moreover, the English phrase [is attributed](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/if_all_you_have_is_a_hammer,_everything_looks_like_a_nail) to either Abraham Maslow or Mark Twain, so it's not exactly an *idiom*. For a quote by some famous person, it is absolutely ok to use a literal translation.

Answer (score 0):

A somewhat similar (albeit not entirely accurate in meaning) expression, "Стрелять по воробьям из пушки" (shooting sparrows with a cannon), means using unreasonably large resources to solve a small task.

Comment: I do not think that this saying conveys similar idea.

Comment: Perhaps you're right... I pointed it out in my answer.

Answer (score -2):

Basically, what the English idiom says is that when you're viewing the world from a particular angle, you're inclined to see certain things, Which reminds me of a similar Russian saying, albeit not quite the same as the English one:

- Куда шея, туда и голова.

('Where the neck goes, the head follows.')

Comment: I agree that this variant is good, though it is not as evil as the English one.